# Comic/graphic novel series about 4 kids traveling to a parallel world

Tags: story-identification, comics, parallel-universe

I’ve been trying to remember the name of a fantasy comic book/graphic novel series that I used to read when I was a kid, around 8 or 9 years old, I was really captivated by it when I first read it, and it’s been stuck in my mind ever since.

It’s about four kids who enter a strange mansion, and through some way or another, end up trapped in a dangerous parallel world. Unfortunately, I can’t really remember any of the plot beyond that. There’s a lanky kid with short black hair, a kid with kind of medium length brown hair, a red-haired kid with glasses, and a black girl with dreadlocks.

The think I remember most about the series was that it was surprisingly dark despite its cartoony style and whimsical premise. It involves themes of parental abuse, torture, and death.

Comment: When was you a kid i.e. when did you read it? Can you remember any of the plot after this point? If you remember anything else please [edit] those details into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think it might be [*The Elsewhere Chronicles*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/bookseries/B00JQY0B7I/ref=dp_st_0761339639)

> It's bad enough when Max, Rebecca, Noah, and Theo just think Grandpa Gabe's house is haunted. But then the old movie projector in the library opens a passageway to a world of monsters and creatures made of shadows - a place of secrets and dangers set loose when the sun sets. The only weapons to fight them lie in the land on the other side of the Shadow Door...
>
> [image]

Comment: Please specify _why_ you think this is the correct answer, within your answer (i.e. which plot points mentioned in the question are also present in this story). We have no way of judging whether this story is the right one or not from the name alone.

Comment: Looking at the cover; lanky kid with short black hair (check), a kid with kind of medium length brown hair (check), a red-haired kid with glasses (check), and a black girl with dreadlocks (check).